# NodeJS out of memory at ~80gib (even though NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=137439)

Tags: node.js, linux, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I'm using the normal `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=137439` to allow for a max of 128Gib of memory of the node process. Still it OOM hard crashes at around ~80Gib memory usage. There appeared to be plentiful avail system memory still free on the machine when it crashed.

Full stack trace:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->                                                                                     
                                                                                                           
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   439376 ms: Scavenge 16006.1 (16534.1) -> 16001.2 (16539.6) MB, 45.9 / 0.0 ms  (ave
rage mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure;                                                   
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   439452 ms: Scavenge 16012.1 (16540.1) -> 16007.4 (16546.1) MB, 45.0 / 0.0 ms  (ave
rage mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure;                                                   
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   440354 ms: Scavenge 16018.1 (16546.1) -> 16013.5 (16546.3) MB, 883.2 / 0.0 ms  (av
erage mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure;                                                  
                                                                                                           
                                                                                                           
<--- JS stacktrace --->                                                                                    
                                                                                                           
                                                                                                           
<--- Last few GCs --->                                                                                     
                                                                                                           
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   439376 ms: Scavenge 16006.1 (16534.1) -> 16001.2 (16539.6) MB, 45.9 / 0.0 ms  (ave
rage mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure;                                                   
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   439452 ms: Scavenge 16012.1 (16540.1) -> 16007.4 (16546.1) MB, 45.0 / 0.0 ms  (ave
rage mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure;                                                   
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   440354 ms: Scavenge 16018.1 (16546.1) -> 16013.5 (16546.3) MB, 883.2 / 0.0 ms  (av
erage mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure;                                                  
                                                                                                           
                                                                                                           
<--- JS stacktrace --->                                                                                    
                                                                                                           
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of
 memory                                                                                                    
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of
 memory   
1: 0x7f2b9e25d6fd node::Abort() [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]                                  [0/1917]
1: 0x7f2b9e25d6fd node::Abort() [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
2: 0x7f2b9df4cbdf node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
2: 0x7f2b9df4cbdf node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
3: 0x7f2b9e5ecf94 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
4: 0x7f2b9e5ed388 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
5: 0x7f2b9e7df80c  [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
6: 0x7f2b9e822ec3 v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]

<--- Last few GCs --->

[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   439376 ms: Scavenge 16006.1 (16534.1) -> 16001.2 (16539.6) MB, 45.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure; 
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   439452 ms: Scavenge 16012.1 (16540.1) -> 16007.4 (16546.1) MB, 45.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure; 
[32212:0x558fcc4af4b0]   440354 ms: Scavenge 16018.1 (16546.1) -> 16013.5 (16546.3) MB, 883.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.855, current mu = 0.671) allocation failure; 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
7: 0x7f2b9e830d47 v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, long*) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
8: 0x7f2b9e80eda5 v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
9: 0x7f2b9e8102b0 v8::internal::PageEvacuationJob::Run(v8::JobDelegate*) [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
10: 0x7f2b9e5d27d7 v8::platform::DefaultJobWorker::Run() [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
11: 0x7f2b9e2d6228  [/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.111]
12: 0x7f2b9d49f8fd  [/usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6]
13: 0x7f2b9d521a60  [/usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It's an Arch Linux system, perhaps I hit some upper bound max memory on the kernel/proc config?

My assumption has always been that `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=XYZ` gives the node process that XYZ amount of space (in Mb) to use before it hits OOM and instead it crashed OOM well before that limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed via:

```bash
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=655300 //10times bigger than default
```

Should work on most Linux flavored systems.

NOTE:You may have to re-run this across re-boots or add it in a more permanent config for persistence on boot

---

Got the memory footprint down to ~20Gib by using `var` instead of `let` in some loops that processed millions of records. Still was getting various weird OOM errors like:

- `FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed`
- `FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Even though system had 128Gib free memory. So must've been some weird memory map thing that was exploding from an array of millions of JSON objs.